# unable to manage bootstrap 4 div elements to the responsive design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with bootstrap 4 and following codes,

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="card-header rounded-0 border border-dark">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 ">
      <img src="{{asset('images/usa.jpg')}}" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 ">
      <p>This is not a game fgfhg dfghdh dhdhdf dfgdhfhg dfdfhfh dfhdfhdf dfhdfh</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need display above two div elements in the same row on large screen and need separate two rows (image is above and paragraph is under the image) when it is displaying mobile device. I use following `col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 item` codes in side to the div but not success.

how could I manage this problem?

Comment: Please clarify the question. "I use following `col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3` item codes" .. where? I don't see that in the code example.

Comment: @Zim I use these `<div class="card-header rounded-0 border border-dark">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 ">
        <img src="{{asset('images/usa.jpg')}}" alt="..." class="rounded-circle">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <p>This is not a game fgfhg dfghdh dhdhdf dfgdhfhg dfdfhfh dfhdfhdf dfhdfh</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>`

Comment: "I need display above two div elements in the same row on large screen and need separate two rows...when it is displaying mobile device". Your code does precisely that: two rows by default, one row on medium (768px) or wider screen (although the `col-12` is redundant and can be removed). Where is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

View in Full Page , You will get it

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  background: #ccc;
}

.other {
  background: #a4a4a4;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.p a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1>Bootstrap Grid Demo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 other">
      <h1>2 Columns</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="p">Demo by Jabir Sayed. <a href="understanding-bootstrap-grid-system">See article</a>.</p>
```